# Identify when a database is in restore state

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm restoring a **database** from backups in Sql Server Management Studio.

This is done in 2 **states**.

1. **Start Restore**. I run a sql script to restore a database (ex: **MyDb**).
2. **Finish Restore**. **MyDb** is restored

How can I identify when a database is in **restore state** (between 1 and 2)?
I want to make an **sql script** that tell me that, if it's possible.

**Note:** I know i can see that from Sql Server Management Studio -> Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the `sys.databases` table:

```
SELECT state FROM sys.databases
```

A state of `1` indicates the database is restoring.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

As @SchmitzIT has pointed out in his answer (+1), and as specified in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx), this data can be retrieved via querying `sys.databases`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.databases
WHERE state = 1
```

If your DB is hanging in `RESTORING` state, you can release it using:

```
RESTORE DATABASE 'DATABASE_NAME' WITH RECOVERY
```